# Sketch the stable/unstable manifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $f: R\rightarrow R$ be continuously differentiable with $(x_0,0)$ is a hyperbolic equilibrium of the system: $\dot{x} = y$, $\dot{y} = -f(x)$.

Sketch the local form of the stable and unstable manifold via their tangent spaces.

**My attempt:** I computed the eigenvalues of $Df((x_0,0))$, and obtained $\pm \sqrt{f'(x_0)}$ as the two eigenvalues. The corresponding stable and unstable subspaces are $E^{s} = span(1\ \  \sqrt{f'(x_0)})$ and $E^{u} = span(1\  \ -\sqrt{f'(x_0)})$. These are the tangent spaces to the stable and unstable manifold, but I don't know how to sketch those manifolds "via these tangent spaces":(

Can anyone please help with the sketch of these manifolds?

Comment: @Lutzl: can you help me with this problem please?

Comment: nobody wants to help me with the diagram? I seriously don't know how to sketch it by hand:p

Comment: @Evgeny: can you give me some help here, based on the info I gave in my original post?